# npm set latest dependencies in package-lock.json

Tags: github, npm, angular6, package-lock.json

Sorry for my overall dumbness and weak understanding of how npm works.

I now work on a project on Angular 6, and github says that hoek package has vulnerabilities.

Running `npm ls hoek` I get this dependency tree:

```
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.6.8
| `-- node-sass@4.9.0
|   +-- node-gyp@3.7.0
|   | `-- request@2.81.0
|   |   `-- hawk@3.1.3
|   |     +-- boom@2.10.1
|   |     | `-- hoek@2.16.3  deduped
|   |     +-- hoek@2.16.3
|   |     `-- sntp@1.0.9
|   |       `-- hoek@2.16.3  deduped
|   `-- request@2.79.0
|     `-- hawk@3.1.3
|       +-- boom@2.10.1
|       | `-- hoek@2.16.3  deduped
|       +-- hoek@2.16.3
|       `-- sntp@1.0.9
|         `-- hoek@2.16.3  deduped
+-- karma@2.0.4
| `-- log4js@2.9.0
|   `-- loggly@1.1.1
|     `-- request@2.75.0
|       `-- hawk@3.1.3
|         +-- boom@2.10.1
|         | `-- hoek@2.16.3  deduped
|         +-- hoek@2.16.3
|         `-- sntp@1.0.9
|           `-- hoek@2.16.3  deduped
```

No matter what I do, `npm install` recreates this dependency tree. As far as I understand, these dependencies are picked up automatically, and to resolve the problem all packages in this tree should update their dependencies, starting from the bottom: first, new versions of `boom`  and `sntp` should start use new version of hoek, then new version of `hawk` should use new versions of `boom`  and `sntp`...

But as far as I've seen on github, some packages in chain are not yet updated.

So, my question is: how can I fix this problem in this project, as for now? Can I manually change dependency versions in package-lock.json (humbly hoping that later versions of lower packages will be compatible with old versions of higher ones)?

Will it resolve my problem in a way, that hoek 2.16.3 will disappear from the project?

Comment: 65 views and not a single comment makes me believe that there is nothing you can do but wait for the all the dependencies in line down to `hoek` to pull up their dependencies, too. Possibly most of them did already, but at least one is missing. :-/